# Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget does not correlate async operations

Tags: .net, asynchronous, nlog, azure-application-insights

My ASP.NET MVC application has NLog configured to redirect anything to Application Insights. Given the following pseudo code:

```
var logger = // resolve NLog logger
logger.Log(Level.Info, "SYNC MESSAGE");
Task.Run(() => logger.Log(Level.Info, "ASYNC MESSAGE"));
```

Both entries appear in Application Insights log but the second one is not correlated with the request. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting operation id/etc set in those async messages, then that probably means that when those log calls occurred, `HttpContext.Current` is null (you could probably verify that by putting a breakpoint inside your lambda call that's doing that second log and checking what the http context is at that time, i'm betting the request is long gone.)

The correlation of ids across places generally gets operation information from the `HttpContext`, so if it isn't set when the messages get logged async, then it just isn't available.

I'm not sure there's any *easy* way to fix this just with the logging adapters, though, if you want to keep the async logging the way you're doing it.